# How to get to the end of the Kubernates containers log

Tags: kubernetes

By running command `kubectl logs pod -c container`

I am getting continuous autoscrolling list of logs. Is there any way I can get to the end or see the latest log. I don't want go through all the logs.

I have tried using -f as well. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `kubectl logs --help`
you can use `--tail`

e.g. `kubectl logs pod --tail=10`

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to see the recent log files, based on number of lines and based on time:

```
kubectl logs --tail=20 nginx
```

It will show you 20 lines of most recent logs

```
kubectl logs --since=1h nginx
```

It will show you logs of last one hour.